# SyntaxError: unexpected token < in JSON at position 868 + Opencart + Centos VPS

Tags: opencart

Suddenly showing error : 
SyntaxError: unexpected token < in JSON at position 868 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ypiI.jpg)

This error is even with the new plain installation fo opencart 2.3 X using softacolous from cpanel.
i have centos VPS server. Also joomla is showing same type of error when java script is minified and compressed using one premium extension.

Also i have noticed that map any analytic in opencart dashboard is not working.

Also also occurs while viewing order, setting etc.

requested to help me.

Comment: try `clearing cache files` from Opencart `Admin` panel.

Comment: I tried clearing cache but noting happened, i tied with 3 different opencart theme, still same, issue, i also curl to latest 7.59.0 , Also installed json encoder, but noting worked.